# Eclipse RCP - How to create and open View programmatically?

Tags: java, view, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to open a View which includes table when operation is executed.

I can open view by viewId by that code:

```
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
        ApplicationGIS.getView(true, viewId);

    }});
```

This view's id defined on plugin.xml but I have to pass some parameters to the table on this view. I can create my custom view programatically but this time i can't open it becuase I don't have its id. Here is my view class:

```
public class MyCustomView extends ViewPart {

    private Text text;
    private Table table;
    private TableViewer tableViewer;


    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

        Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 4, 1));
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        Composite composite_1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1));
        GridLayout gl_composite_1 = new GridLayout(1, false);
        gl_composite_1.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        gl_composite_1.marginHeight = 0;
        gl_composite_1.marginWidth = 0;
        gl_composite_1.verticalSpacing = 0;
        composite_1.setLayout(gl_composite_1);

        tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        table = tableViewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

So how can I access this programmatically created view and open it?

Comment: What Eclipse version do you use 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: I am using 3.x. btw I will try your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.x you can open a View like this:

```
MyView view = (MyView) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewer_ID);
```

Or if you are implementing a command handler, you can call:

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView(viewId);
```

To set some content you can simply add a method like `void setInput(MyContent input)` to your ViewPart and pass the needed arguments to this method, after opening it.

Comment: What is Viewer at `MyView view = (MyView Viewer)` ?. I tried like this  `MyView view = (MyView) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewer_ID);` but it threw null pointer exception.

Comment: Sorry, it was a Typo! The NPE comes probably because call was not made in the UI-Thread or the workbench is not start yet. Try to wrap the code with `Display#asyncExec(..)` or a WorkbenchJob.

Comment: RCP views have a big limitation, as they are instantiated by the workbench and do not support manual instantiation (abstract methods cannot be used). Yes, you can pass arguments through a method after creation, but you cannot return values from the view!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  I wanted to create additional views from the one registered in the plugin.  These URL's will get you what you want:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_multiple_instances_of_the_same_view

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-one-viewpart.html

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
getActivePage().showView(String viewID,String secondaryID,int Mode);
```

Comment: The question addresses another problem (passing a parameter to a created view). Your answer shows how to open MULTIPLE instances of the same view (using the "secondaryId" of the view)

Answer (score 0):

From @Chriss answer;

I added a method `setInput(parameter)` to my view and then I can pass my values to my custom view like this

```
    MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView();     
    view.setInput(parameter);
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
        ApplicationGIS.getView(true, viewId);


    }});
```

and this works.

Comment: The View should be created by the extension point, not by your self. Otherwise you might get some trouble later.

Comment: if my answer works feel free to mark it as "answered"

Comment: RCP views are instantiated by the workbench... i don't understand your code! Why are you instantiating the view? You should FIND the view after it is opened and then set the "input"... your code should not work at all :\